# Resizable Nav Bar Is Not Stacking Properly

Tags: css

The website in question is http://oxfordbeach.com/bynight/

If you resize the browser, the nav bar will eventually go into a drop down menu for iPhone.
But when it's around 900px wide, the nav bar cannot fit the "contact" list item.

I apologize for the elementary CSS question, but I've tried:

- Resizing the header to a %
- Resizing the nav bar class to a %
- Resizing the individual list items

However, I cannot seem to get around the fact that when the browser is around 900px, give or take a 100, the nav bar does not render properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reducing the padding on the links from 30px to 25px will do:

```
.sf-menu li a {
    padding: 0 25px;
}
```

you can also set this padding to be % instead of fixed px to make the menu more responsive - I will leave the calculation to you!